# Can't download 4.14.11-300.fc27.x86_64 kernel

Tags: linux, virtualbox, fedora

I am trying to use VirtualBox, but I get the error

```
The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (4.14.11-300.fc27.x86_64) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

When running the suggested command, I get:

```
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
```

However, when I run `sudo yum install kernel-devel gcc`, it installs the version `4.15.3-300.fc27`, which differs from my actual kernel version, that is `4.14.11-300.fc27.x86_64`.

Also, when running `sudo yum install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"`, I get

```
No match for argument: kernel-devel-uname-r == 4.14.11-300.fc27.x86_64
Error: Unable to find a match
```

What should I do to get VirtualBox running?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

> However, when I run sudo yum install kernel-devel gcc, it installs the version 4.15.3-300.fc27, which differs from my actual kernel version, that is 4.14.11-300.fc27.x86_64.

That's because 4.15.3 is, as of this writing, the current kernel update for Fedora 27. You *could* download the devel package for the older kernel, but the best option is to update the kernel (I'd recommend doing a general `dnf update` of everything), and *then* install the kernel devel package, and then finally reboot into that kernel and complete your VirtualBox installation.

Comment: You may also consider using Fedora's native qemu-kvm virtualization (run `virt-manager` or `boxes`) rather than VirtualBox, if you just need a VM and don't particularly need VirtualBox specifically. Then, you don't have to mess with any of this.